# Where to locate automysqlbackup.sh [AutoMySQLBackup] at Bluehost? [secure issue]

Tags: mysql, security, backup, bluehost

After having seriously database loosing problems, I decided to go for an autobackup system. I researched and [AutoMySQLBackup](http://sourceforge.net/projects/automysqlbackup/) looks fine.

I use Bluehost, where should I locate the automysqlbackup.sh file? I just worry about security issue. Also, where should we locate the backup files?

Appreciate! thanks a lot!

Comment: Are you sure you have enough access rights to run shell scripts?

Comment: hmm, good question. Im not sure. Im going to try that with Cron Jobs from Bluehost admin panel.

Comment: BTW, almost every hoster has own backups, especially on shared plans.

Comment: bluehost doesnt give that to me. First thing it was i have asked. I dont remember very well, but they said sth like autoback service is for over 2GB hosted sites. etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know bluehost, but definitely put it outside the web root if you can. If you can't, create a new directory, put the shell script and a .htaccess file saying

```
Deny from all
```

in it. That should block it for access from outside with a 403 error - make sure you test.

Putting it outside the web root is the way better option IMO, especially if it contains sensitive data.