# Where to place and how to access db_connect info for MySQL and PHP

Tags: php, mysql, security, connection

I'm working on a project that needs to have users log into a MySQL database. I'm working through making an authentication system(auth/user table with their names, email, hashed password etc, php session), its more work than I realized but am making my way through it. I'm a little confused on the initial connection to the database though. I've read to keep it [outside of the document root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2348789/where-is-the-most-secure-place-to-put-mysql-connection-details-for-php) for the site, which I can do, but not sure how to reference it. Here is what I was thinking:

Document root for site:

**/var/www/public/example.com/public/** {index.html,css,img,etc}

Could I safely place the db_connect info here:

**/var/www/public/example.com/private/** securephpfunctions.php

I'd then have one line in all my php files:

```
<?php
// include in all files that need to do stuff
require_once('examplecom_fns.php'); 
?>
```

Inside examplecom_fns.php is:

```
<?php
// include in all files
require_once('/var/www/public/example.com/private/securephpfunctions.php');
require_once('forms_fns.php');
require_once('outputs_fns.php');
?>
```

After this, I assume I can call my DB connect function to insert new users info into the DB, use for not signed in users searching public entires, etc. Is that correct/OK? Is there a better or more secure way to do what I'm trying? Am I way off base?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reference your document root with the following:

```
$_ENV['document_root'];
```

Then, by adding a relative path, you can get your private path:

```
realpath($_ENV['document_root'] . '../private');
```

Then add to that the name of your private config file:

```
realpath($_ENV['document_root'] . '../private/securephpfunctions.php');
```

Comment: I've run into another issue and haven't been able to confirm, but after other reading this seems to be what I'll need to do, I'll accept as the answer, and thank you!