# Can I host a Wordpress plugin myself but allow other users to benefit from it?

Tags: php, facebook, wordpress

I'm developing a Wordpress plugin that requires API credentials for Facebook.

Ordinarily I'd advise the users of the plug-in to sign up for their own API keys and allow them to be entered as plug-in options, however this plug-in requires extended permissions. Which as I'm currently in the process of finding out are an absolute ball-ache to get, take up-to 7 businesses days to have reviewed and the reviewers don't actually read the requested instructions on how the application is being used.

Can I write a plugin that is basically a wrapper around my hosted version of the code, this way I can allow users of the plugin the benefits of the extended permissions without giving away my APP ID and APP SECRET

Thinking something like...

```
require_once("https://www.myplugin.com/FacebookPlugin.php");
```

Here's the obvious problem, this wouldn't work for hosted versions of Wordpress as they don't have access to plug-ins anyway and I believe it would require the owner to allow remote file inclusion, which is putting a lot of trust in me as the host of the remote file not to execute nasty scripts on their server.

So how do I offer the functionality of my plugin to other users?

Comment: @MarcB did you even read what the post said about remote file inclusion ?

Comment: @MarcB Oh that's definitely going to be an issue. URL Include wrappers have to be enabled for it to work this way. Source: http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php
You can't force webistes to enable such wrappers when distributing your WordPress plugin.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Storing important secret keys in php files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2311492/storing-important-secret-keys-in-php-files)

Comment: I know I could unset the variables in the plugin, but the user would still have the source code with them in. So its not really about securing them at all.

Comment: Look at my answer. In that way, you will not need to hard code the API Keys anymore, but you can request them to a service hosted by you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this question is closely related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2311492/storing-important-secret-keys-in-php-files).

I do not think there's more you can do, except still having your separate server which can be triggered using [HttpRequest::send](http://php.net/manual/en/httprequest.send.php) from within the plugin, and ship encrypted Keys from there each time somebody is accessing your plugin.

Might be a performance-Killing approach, though, especially if your server is not that fast.