# Encryption: How good a key should be?

Tags: php, encryption, encryption-symmetric

I have the following code:

```
<?php
public function Encrypt($plaintext)
{
    // $key = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(32);
    // key must be same random generation need to save key while generating
    $key = 1;
    $ivlen = openssl_cipher_iv_length($cipher="AES-128-CBC");
    $iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($ivlen);
    $ciphertext_raw = openssl_encrypt($plaintext, $cipher, $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
    $hmac = hash_hmac('sha256', $ciphertext_raw, $key, true);
    $ciphertext = base64_encode($iv.$hmac.$ciphertext_raw);
    return $ciphertext;
}

public function Decrypt($ciphertext)
    {
        //algo to decrypt same cipher text for decrypting later....
        // $key = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(32);
        // key must be same random generation need to save key while generating
        $key = 1;
        $c = base64_decode($ciphertext);
        $ivlen = openssl_cipher_iv_length($cipher="AES-128-CBC");
        $iv = substr($c, 0, $ivlen);
        $hmac = substr($c, $ivlen, $sha2len=32);
        $ciphertext_raw = substr($c, $ivlen+$sha2len);
        $original_plaintext = openssl_decrypt($ciphertext_raw, $cipher, $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
        $calcmac = hash_hmac('sha256', $ciphertext_raw, $key, true);
        if (hash_equals($hmac, $calcmac)) {
            return $original_plaintext;
        }
    }

    ?>
```

I have 2 questions:
Based on the code I provided, if an intruder put the `$key = 1` would he be able to decrypt the plaintext input? does it matter to have a very strong `$key` in this case? Are we relying on how good `$key` value should be?

Second question, `($cipher="AES-128-CBC")` is sufficient in your opinion? Or should I put `AES-256-CBC` ?

Comment: If someone has the key, yes they can decrypt. You have the key and you can, so why wouldn't they be able to run the same code with the same key? Or am I missing something?

Comment: This site has a [good discussion](https://www.ubiqsecurity.com/blog/128bit-or-256bit-encryption-which-to-use/) on 128 vs 256. Ultimately we can't answer this for you because we don't know what you are securing and what your threat model is.

Comment: So basically the key is the most important part?

Comment: What is the best approach to make a very strong key?

Comment: The recommendation is to use what you have commented out, `$key = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes()`. For 128, you want a 16 byte key, and for 256 you want a 32 byte key. You'll probably have to store this key as base64 somewhere, too. **Storing** the key securely is very, very important.

Comment: @ChrisHaas Thank you, okay how to store the key securely? Sorry if I keep asking

Comment: There are many ways you can do this, with various levels of complexity, which once again corresponds to your threat model. Are you protecting national secrets, family recipes, or something in between? If the information gets out, does someone die, is a country invaded, do you pay someone $1,000,000, or do you just say "oops, sorry". We can't answer this for you, but this the key is sometimes called a "secret" and you can look for "secret management" or "secret storage". At a minimum, I'd do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2311514/231316).

Comment: Yeah makes sense, thank you. It's highly appreciated dear @ChrisHaas
Just a quick last question, I'm not sure why when I do `Encrypt("encrypt-this");` it doesn't show me the new cypher even there is a `return $ciphertext;`

Comment: What do you mean by "show"? There's no `echo` so nothing would be visible? Or am I not understanding?

Comment: I'm testing by calling the function `Encrypt()` then insert data to it `Encrypt("encrypt-this"); `in my function you can notice that i have `return $ciphertext;` or maybe I'm doing it wrong

Comment: When I run `var_dump(Decrypt(Encrypt('test')))` I see a result, beyond that I'm not sure what you are looking for

Comment: I'm looking to encrypt the string "encrypt-this" from plaintext to encrypted line then return the result

Comment: `$encrypted = Encrypt('encrypt-this');` then do something with the variable?

Comment: Perform hexadecimal or base 64 encoding of the return value, the return value may include things like zero valued bytes, you've specified RAW mode after all. AES ciphertext is fully randomized. The function should default to base 64 if you leave RAW out...